# モジュールの戻り値の設計について

Tags: ruby-on-rails, プログラミング言語, 詳細設計

Webアプリケーションを作成しているのですが、moduleの戻り値の設計についてどうすれば良いのか悩んでいます。

「usersモデルのuser_nameを更新する」という単純なmoduleを作成することを例にしてみます。

```
module UserNameUpdate
  def update(user, user_name)
    if user.blank?
      return xxx
    end

    if user_name.blank?
      return xxx
    end

    user.update!(user_name: user_name)
  end
end
```

引数がnilでないことや、必要であれば型もチェックするかもしれません。
hashで返してみることやstringで返すことも考えてみましたが、奥が深くて指針となるようなドキュメントを読んでみたいです。

```
module UserNameUpdate
  def update(user, user_name)
    hash = {
      code: 1,
      message: nil
    }

    if user.blank?
      hash['message'] = '引数のmessageがnilです'
      return hash
    end

    if user_name.blank?
      hash['message'] = '引数のuser_nameがnilです'
      return hash
    end

    user.update!(user_name: user_name)
  end
end
```

戻り値はどう設計するのがベストでしょうか。Ruby/Railsに関係なく普遍的な問題かと思っていますので、言語/FWは特に限定はしないです。
ドキュメントや良いアイディアがあれば教えていただけますでしょうか。

あと、タグって何を付けるのが適切ですかね。。それっぽいタグが無く。。

Comment: Go言語はエラー情報を別に返す機構を持っていたりしますし、例外がある言語ない言語など、言語によって設計は大きく変わると思います。また、ご自身のソースにある RoR の機能 `user.update!` の設計思想などがヒントになるかもしれません。

Comment: @shingo.nakanishi 
update!の設計思想というのは、失敗した場合にErrorを起こすということでしょうか。
言語やFWは限定した方が良いかもしれないですね。

Comment: そういうことです。 一方`!` のない `user.update` 例外を起こさない形式もあります。これだけみてもRoRで少なくとも2つの設計があるので、ご質問に適切な回答をつけるのは難しのではないかと考えています。（このようにスタックオーバーフローは回答に個人の見解などが含まれてしまうようなもの、複数回答がいくらでも用意できてしまうものは向いていない思想だったはずです）

Comment: おっしゃる通り、言語やFW、ご自身がなさりたいある程度の設計方針などあったほうが良いように思います。

Comment: 抽象的なテーマの質問はあまりよくないということですね。もう少し思案してみます。

Answer (score 0):

@shingo.nakanishi さんも仰っていますが、言語・FW(が提供する機能)によって、適切な設計は変わってくると思います。おそらく、最終的に質問者様が知りたいのは、 rails において今回の機能を実装する場合の正しい(たしからしい)方法は何か、だと思っています。

その前提で回答をすると、今回はカラムの値チェックがほぼなので、 [rails tutorial にある active record validation](https://railsguides.jp/active_record_validations.html) に従うのが、 rails 的な実装なのではないかと思います。

抜粋して説明してみますと、カラムに対する値チェックならば、

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

のように宣言的に記述することが可能です。

Comment: 今回の例ではuser_nameがnilかどうかの検証しか載せていませんが、実際には関連する別モデルの状態の確認やファイルの扱いなどが絡み、railsのvalidatesだけでは実現することが難しいような検証を行います。